# Свой проект на Github и свободные шрифты

Tags: github, шрифты, лицензирование, авторские-права

Можно ли в проект на Github включить файлы свободных шрифтов? Cтоит ли все-таки указывать автора шрифта, текст лицензии на шрифт и проч, если лицензия автора явно этого не требует ("No attribution or backlinks are required") или если используется лицензия Apache.

Comment: от того, что Вы добавите информацию о авторстве шрифтов (и других файлов) с указанием, где именно взяли, хуже не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если лицензия позволяет использование шрифтов в проектах Open Sources - то почему бы и не включить эти шрифты в репозиторий.

Большинство лицензий при этом требуют указать автора и лицензию оригинальных файлов.

Лицензия Apache, например, явно предписывает предоставлять копию лицензии и данные об авторстве.

Свободные шрифты часто публикуются под лицензиями Creative Commons. Я не очень силён в этой группе лицензий, но, насколько я понимаю, разные версии этой лицензии предъявляют различные требования к указанию авторства, при этом все виды подразумевают указание версии лицензии оригинального произведения. Думаю, по поводу лицензий CC Вы можете ознакомиться со [статьёй](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_Creative_Commons) в Википедии.

Comment: Ну это я понимаю. Меня больше интересуют тонкости. КАК упоминать авторство? Отдельным файлом лицензии? тогда в проекте будет две лицензии - на код и на шрифт? Или одним файлом? Или в коде комментарий оставить? Или хватит на главной странице проекта ссылки?

Comment: @qtm, заведи отдельную папку, `3rdpart`, а в ней подпапку `название-репозитория-шрифта`. Вот в эту подпапку и складывай шрифт и лицензию к нему.

Comment: Спасибо, это лучший вариант.